# A Scroll which appears to be from 2004 signed 包德和

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters, classical-chinese

包德和 Bāo dé hé      Longevity Scroll
Which I think reads something like '50 Things to buy for an Emperor'
Unfortunately I am still learning Chinese characters.

- Who is the Caligraphy Writer?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *Who is the Calligraphy Writer?*

You said it, it was signed by "包德和". logically thinking -- "包德和" must had written it.

The seal wrote: 長樂 (always/ forever happy)

The part of the scroll you posted wrote "鵬飛王五十壽辰"

- 鵬飛王 = Peng Fei Wang (*may be a person's name, but can also be a brand name. 3rd January 2020 was Apple's 44th Birthday*)
- 五十 = 50(th)
- 壽辰 = birthday